# Xcode app run on simulator but not on device

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

i've saw a lot of topic but no one answers to my questions.
This Program run on simulator but when i executed it , it crash . 
This is my simple code.  Thanks you!

```
 NSURL *url=[NSURL fileURLWithPath:@"/Users/marco/Desktop/Letters/1.txt"];
 NSString *fileContent = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:url];
 NSLog(@"fileContent = %@", fileContent);
 NSArray * a = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:fileContent, nil];
 Output.text=[a objectAtIndex:0];
 NSLog (@"The 4th integer is: %@", a);
```

Comment: that url doesnt exist on your device ?

Comment: There is no way, without a jailbreak, you could ever access a file which resides outside of your apps sandbox.

Answer (score 0):

Move your `1.txt` file to your device, for example your documents folder.

Then change the first line of your app like so:

```
NSString *documentsPath = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) firstObject];
NSString *filePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/1.txt", documentsPath];
NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:filePath];
```

Comment: Or, the file can be added to `Copy Bundle Resources` in the build phases.

Answer (score 0):

Since you say this works on the simulator, I'll have to assume you added this file to your project properly. If not, add the file to your project and target. You can get the URL to any resource you included at build time through `NSBundle`:

```
NSBundle *bundle = [NSBundle bundleForClass:[self class]]; // often you will see [NSBunble mainBundle, but both work
NSURL *url = [bundle URLForResource:@"1" withExtension:@"txt"];
```